# How do I chat about a question if the asker has too low rep for chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

I encountered a question which turns out to need more back and forth, and that is is inappropriate for comments. But the chat system won't let the questioner in because his rep is only 7 and 20 is required.

Suggestion: why not allow a member with sufficient rep to do a one-time invite of a low rep member to a single specific chat?

Question: what is appropriate route for this case? I've suggested IRC but I don't know if this is appropriate. I do not want to give out my email.

Comment: Care to give us an example question? Perhaps there is a better alternative than taking it to chat.

Comment: This was the most recent question I tried to help with: http://serverfault.com/questions/443221/ec2-filesystem-files-stored-on-the-wrong-partiton-after-launching-new-instance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got two choices: If the comment train gets long enough you'll be prompted to **automatically** create a room for both of you. You'll both get invitations and life's pretty easy from there.

There is a **manual** way; unfortunately it's still kinds of difficult:

1. Send user a link to the room where you want to chat. Note, you must be an owner of the room ([create a new room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) or Bug-A-Mod for The Comms Room).
2. After the low-rep user has "entered" they'll get the notice about "Must have 20 Rep...". You will see their icon in top-right; hover over the icon and note their User ID (usually a 5 digit number).
3. On the "Room" menu (also top-right, just over the user icons) select "Control Access"
4. On the next page, there's a section for "Explicit write access", click the "Add a user" button, enter their User ID from above, click "grant".
5. ...
6. PROFIT!

After you've done it, it's not that bad, but almost nobody would guess that.

PS> Don't worry about creating superfluous rooms, they auto delete after a couple weeks of inactivity.

Comment: I did try the prompted option to create the chat room at the time (because the comments had gotten long already and it was automatically detected). But when I clicked on that, it did not create the room, and instead told me the other member only had rep of 7 and 20 was needed.  I didn't know the other manual way, but will try it the next time this kind of thing happens (hopefully sooner in the comment thread).

Comment: Sounds like a fun error... I tried the "manual" process with a brand new 1 rep user and it worked fine, so I know that much works for me at least.

Comment: Thanks. That's the approach I'll go for next.